# Apply primary-toolbar background behind GtkEntry widget with GTK3

Tags: application-development, python, gtk3, pygi, style

In PyGI (GTK3), how can I make a GtkEntry widget appear against the same background applied (by the user's theme) to the primary toolbar. I tried adding the same style class like this:

```
entry.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)
```

but that class doesn't seem to be observed on a widget that isn't a GtkToolbar. So how can I cue the user's theme to apply the same styles behind a GtkEntry widget?

(If it matters, I have the GtkEntry in the first cell of a GtkHBox container. But even when I apply a fixed gradient to that HBox the whole cell holding the GtkEntry seems to mask out the background of the HBox with a flat background colour.)

Thanks.

Comment: You would need to add the class to the style context of the container of the entry, and not the entry itself.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately the class doesn't do anything on non-toolbar widgets (e.g., an HBox or VBox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called primary-toolbar style because it should be applied only to primary toolbar.

In Gtk, toolbars by default can hold only ToolButtons, but there is the ToolItem class, which does not have a visual represntation.

That is created because it can embed other widgets.
ToolItem has add method which you can use like :

my_tool_item.add(my_box)
where my_box contains your entry

Then you can add your tool item to toolbar
my_toolbar.insert(my_tool_item,index)

Your toolbar of course has called :
get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR)

The reason why you cannot use "primary-toolbar" with non Toolbar widgets is most probably because in .css files it is defined like :

```
GtkToolbar.primary-toolbar 

{

    /* style info*/

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandar. I didn't realize that I would embed other widgets (aside from buttons) in a toolbar like this. It's kind of hidden in glade (which I'm using for ui design), but I finally realized that when I edit the widget hierarchy in glade for a GtkToolbar I can add a new item of the type "custom." That "custom" item type is the generic GtkToolItem. Then I was able to add my GtkEntry widget normally with glade's interface.

Comment: No problem. I am glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You did not say, why you can't use a toolbar, so I will suggest exactly that:

replace the HBox by a toolbar, give that toolbar the Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_PRIMARY_TOOLBAR style and you should be done...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, xubuntix. The trick was that I didn't know how to embed a GtkEntry widget in a toolbar. I've figured that out now, so I was able to use a toolbar after all.